# How can I make slimes unable to despawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a 'pet shop' and I am selling cats dogs and slimes. Of course, the cats and dogs don't de-spawn, but slimes do.

I tried to gave them names (using name tags) and I thought that would work, but it didn't. Does anyone know another way of stopping them from despawning?

Comment: Willing to use commands?

Comment: I just tested it in my redstone world. Named slimes of all sizes *do not despawn*. However, slimes are notorious for suffocation in walls, which is likely what happened to your slimes.

Comment: but there were no slime balls anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop mobs from despawning?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239801/how-can-i-stop-mobs-from-despawning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All entities can have a `PersistenceRequired` tag, which can stop them from despawning. If you are willing to use commands, you can stop slimes spawning like this:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Slime] {PersistenceRequired:1b}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i was building this in creative

Comment: You can do this in creative mode.

Comment: i did it but they still doespawned, i really dont know why. i was keeping them a 5x2 area and its quite well lit with glowstone.

Comment: @alixey999 Are you sure they are not dying?

Answer (score -1):

This cannot be done in survival unless it is withing a 128 block radius as stated. You can achieve this in creative mode using the tag: "{PersistenceRequired:1}". This can be manually added to a mob using /entitydata.